# WP7 Add Ipad (Copy, paste, cut) like Menus in Windows phone 7.1

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on a windows phone application and i need Menu like Ipad text selected (Cut,copy,paste) and also want some custom menus. When i Select text in windows phone only one option Copy text is visible.

Suggest me the Solution to my problem.

Thanx

**EDIT**

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" Padding="6">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1" Click="Item1_Click" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item2" Click="Item2_Click" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item3" Click="Item3_Click" />
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <TextBlock Text="Tap" />
</Border>

private void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Border border = sender as Border;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(border);
    if (contextMenu.Parent == null)
    {
        contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

I have used This code but it Generates a context menu like list items which i Not required I requires a Round corner Image icons like Copy and paste Or it would like the ipad or iphone selection text menu.

I want menu like

[image: Text Selection]

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @ss1271 I have Updated the Question Please Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my Question and Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679387/link-within-a-page-not-working-in-windows-phone-webbrowser)

and then Add Gesture event listner like below code Also note that you have to include the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit reference.

```
GestureListener listener = new GestureListener();
        listener.Hold += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // some logic here
            textSelectionMenu.Tag = args;
            textSelectionMenu.SelectedItem = null;
            textSelectionMenuPopup.IsOpen = true;
            activePopup = textSelectionMenuPopup;
            textSelectionMenu.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            Size selectionMenuSize = textSelectionMenu.DesiredSize;
            System.Windows.Point pt = args.GetPosition(textSelectionMenu);
            double offsetX = 50;
            double offsetY = pt.Y;

            // Finally, make sure it's on the screen
            //offsetX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(offsetX, selectionMenuSize.Width));
            //offsetY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(offsetY, selectionMenuSize.Height));

            textSelectionMenuPopup.HorizontalOffset = offsetX;
            textSelectionMenuPopup.VerticalOffset = offsetY;
        };
        this.Browser.SetValue(GestureService.GestureListenerProperty, listener);
```