# Link within a page not working in Windows phone webbrowser

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am using Web browser Control in Windows phone 7 and I want to navigate within page as

```
<ul>
 <li>
    <a href="#chapter-1_xhtml">Section 1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="#chapter-2_xhtml">Section 2</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

then i use

```
<a name="chapter-1_xhtml" id="chapter-1_xhtml"></a>
...............The Div and other code..............
<a name="chapter-2_xhtml" id="chapter-2_xhtml"></a>
...............The Div and other code..............
```

It works perfectly in Desktop browsers but when i run the same code in Windows phone emulator its not working and after a jerk it stays there.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Adding the Function to Html

```
function ScrollTo(Id) {
        document.getElementById(Id).scrollIntoView();
    }
```

and Calling the Following code on button click achieved my Goal.

```
this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("ScrollTo", "chapter-1_xhtml");
```